# Margins aren't applying to my image

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having trouble getting margins to work on an image. I have an image, and it has the following CSS:

```
#logoRedrum{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;

    margin-top:auto;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

The HTML for the image is as follows:

`<img id="logoRedrum" src="resources/img/logoRedrum.png">`

What I'm trying to do with this is to have my image centered **at all times**. Instead of having it centered, it is doing this:

[image: It's really annoying!]

The red backwards "R" with the blue outline is my image. I have googled several times what might be causing the image to stay on the left, but to no avail.

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: margin right and left should be `auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to `img`

```
#logoRedrum{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
  display:block;
    margin:0 auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mewezudi/2/)**

Comment: Ah, that's the ticket. Thanks! I'll pick this answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to center the image in the main parent its easy, do it like this

//HTML

```
<div class="centered-content"> <img class="no-margin" src=""/> </div>
```

//CSS

```
.contered-content {
    text-align:center;
    }
.no-margin{
   margin:0 auto;
 }
```